# Node.js, Mongoose, Express - Validate user input for longitude and latitude

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Im looking for advice on how best to validate a long/lat value that is saved to Mongodb via an Express API route.

I have seen examples where a min and a max value can be defined in the model but I cannot get this to work. Here is my current model - see "geo":

```
var placeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
name: String,
geo: { type : [Number], index: '2d'},
tags: { type : [String], index: true },
create_date : {type: Date, "default": Date.now()}
});
```

I could also validate at the route level, or using a pre('save') event within he model.

Can anyone advise where I should be doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about these codes

```
placeSchema.path('geo').validate(function(geo){
   // do validation here
   // return geo.longitude > 0;
}, 'Longitude should be larger than 0');
```